# Page layout standards for academic articles

Tags: article

I have acquired TeX/LaTeX experience to the point where I feel comfortable with controlling different parameters of my document, specifically dealing with academic articles.

And I don't like the default article.cls layout. But regardless, I could adjust the parameters the way I like. But at the same time, I would prefer if I conform to some layout standards, preferably backed by typesetting/typography research. In such discussions, the name of Tufte comes up a lot, however I'm not aware of much details about his work.

So is there any resource about various standard page layouts for academic articles, or demos of page layouts that I can look at and pick the one I like?

Comment: My advice: don't bother. If your article is accepted, the journal will impose house layout. If your article is not accepted, very few people will see it. This is good advice which I persistently ignore.

Comment: Change to `scrartcl.cls` and experiment with the DIV= factor. Then you will have type block and margins etc. set to proportions recommended by typographers.

Comment: I would suggest one of the established standards like IEEEtrans.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Really? Isn't that rather discipline dependent? Unless it is generally used in all journals in your discipline or you know where you will submit, tying your mark up to that class will just create unnecessary work later. Better stick to `article` and keep the format as simple as possible until later.

Answer (score 2):

Many journals provide LaTeX templates for authors. See for example

- [PLoS](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/s/latex)
- [REVTeX by the APS](http://journals.aps.org/revtex)
- [a large collection of templates](http://www.latextemplates.com/cat/academic-journals)

Comment: OH NO, the template site ... ;-)